# selenium not reading javascript alert in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

i am using selenium ide for testing my .net website.
i am testing login for the website by using selenium.
i recorded the steps and as i am testing the code in visual studio the test case is failing.
my test case is:

```
selenium.Open("//login.aspx");
            selenium.Type("fldUsername", "abc");
            selenium.Type("fldPassword", "abc");
            selenium.Click("btnLogin");
            bool log1 = selenium.IsPromptPresent();
            Assert.IsNull(log1);
            selenium.WaitForPageToLoad("80000");
```

here username and password are incorrect and is giving a alert. but using selenium it is not getting that alert.
please someone help me out..

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong method.  `selenium.IsPromptPresent()` looks for JavaScript `window.prompt()` calls.  For `window.alert()`, you need to use `selenium.IsAlertPresent()`.

For extra credit, replace those two lines with:

```
Assert.True(selenium.IsAlertPresent());
Assert.AreEqual("your expected alert text", selenium.GetAlert());
```

That way you make sure that you're getting the "wrong userid/password" alert, not the "no password specified" alert or something else.

Comment: after clicking on login button it is taking sometime to validate user, but as per program it will never trace the popup..and when i use selenium.waitforpagetoload, it is giving an exception of time out.....

Comment: Oops - it should have been "IsAlertPresent()", not "IsPromptPresent()".  I've updated the suggestion.